# Is there any reason to use Meteor Towers over Missile Towers?

Tags: defense-grid-2

In the first Defense Grid game, Missile Towers had an important, unique role: they were the most effective thing for shooting down flying aliens.  But there are no flying aliens in Defense Grid 2, so Missile Towers have been reworked to... essentially the same thing as Meteor Towers, as far as I can tell.

They're *slightly* more expensive, but not by much, they have the same extreme range, lower damage but they more than make up for it with a much higher rate of fire and a far better projectile velocity.  It makes me wonder, is there any good reason to prefer Meteor Towers over Missile Towers?

Answer (score 1):

The area damage on meteor towers is nice for softening up large groups of weak enemies, and so I will frequently put a meteor tower near the beginning of the enemy's approach so it will focus on newly entered groups with plenty of targets to hit.  A meteor tower that dumps fire at a single hard target is wasting fire, and that's what it will do - if it can reach those targets.  If it can only reach new packs, that's what it will fire at and it will strip quite a bit of health off of them.

Missile towers I have farther back so they can shell things that survive the walk through the initial gauntlet of fire.  I use lots of missile towers - they are awesome - but they are better at single target damage.

Comment: I believe Meteor towers also can attack around obstacles better thanks to their near vertical firing arc. they don't seem to need complete line of sight to the target to fire at it, unlike missiles which have almost no arc and and must have a near straight line to their target.